# how to set up database

Tags: database, database-design, schema

I’m creating an app that tracks attendance of players in amateur football teams. And I’m just not sure how to set up the database. A bit of info: every user has a team and should only see the events within his team per season.

These are the main things:

- Users
- Events
- User stats (for later)
- Events

  - Training / match / social
  - Date
  - Time
  - Subject / opponent
  - Attendance

Main questions:

- Do I make an event table per team per season? Or do I put all events in one big table for every user?
- What is the best way to handle the attendance? They should be able to choose from

  - Present
  - absent
  - Fan

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
User
    userid PK
    Name
    
Team
    teamid PK
    TeamName
    
UserInTeam
    userid FK
    teamid FK
    
Event
    eventid PK
    home_teamid FK
    visiting_teamid FK
    eventtypeid FK
    Date
    Time
    Subject / opponent
    Attendance
    
Event type
    eventtypeid PK
    EventType
    
Attendance Type
    attendanceid PK
    AttendanceType
    
UserAtEvent
    userid FK
    eventid FK
    attendancetypeid FK
```

Content of Event Type

```
1   Training
2   Match
3   Social
```

Content of Attendance Type

```
1   Present
2   Absent
3   Fan
```

For Event, `home_teamid` and `visiting_teamid` can be NULL if the event is not a match

The application will show the events based on the team the user is a member of.